# Migrating from protractor to cypress in angular giving error

Tags: typescript, protractor, cypress, angular8

I am trying to migrate protractor e2e tests to cypress. The first step was to run this command:`ng add @cypress/schematic`
It went well, but now when I type `ng e2e` I get an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
> See "C:\Users\WAEL~1.ABB\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Nojsrx\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I am using angular 8, "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.24"
I tried all other minor versions for devkit but still same error. Any clues?

**angular.json:**

```js
"e2e": {
  "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
  "options": {
    "devServerTarget": "proj:serve",
    "watch": true,
    "headless": false
  },
  "configurations": {
  "production": {
    "devServerTarget": "proj:serve:production"
  }
}
```

Error log:

> [error] Error: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
> at Observable._subscribe (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\experimental\jobs\simple-scheduler.js:350:23)
> at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
> at Observable.subscribe (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
> at C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
> at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
> at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
> at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
> at C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
> at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\work\proj-Branches\wip3\proj\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)

Comment: Post the contents of your angular.json, please - that's where `ng e2e` is configured. And maybe the detailed log of that error would be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a versioning issue.

You have a tag for `angular8`, is this the version you are running? I note that Angular no longer support v8 and lower.

Plus `@cypress/schematic` was released this year, likely it's not compatible.

---

I tested the Angular 8 starter app + @cypress/schematic, and trying to run `ng e2e` gives the same error.

However, running "standard" Cypress command

```js
yarn cypress open

or

npx cypress open
```

will open the Cypress runner and tests under `/cypress/integration` run ok.

Also, manually start the Angular dev server - `ng start` so that the app is accessible at `http://localhost:4200`.

Comment: Yes correct the project is still angular 8, so to use cypress, better first update to a more recent version of angular like angular 10 or directly angular 12?

Comment: I had a look for a release note or "peerDependencies" entry to show what Angular version `@cypress/schematic` supported, but found none. Can confirm I get the same error with Angular 8 starter + @cypress/schematic.